# Suggesting solutions for Sympy solve

Tags: python, optimization, sympy, solver

I'm trying to solve an equation using SymPy's `solve` for many different values of inputs. Here is my code so far:

```
E = np.linspace(Emin,Emax,((Emax-Emin)/Emesh)+1)
z1 = np.zeros(len(E))+0j

for i in xrange(len(E)):    
    z = Symbol('z')
    z1[i] = solve( (d - E[i])/s - z - 1/z, z)
```

Here `d` and `s` are constants and `E` is a one dimensional array. The code works fine but it is very slow. Because the `E[i]` vary slowly, `z1[i]` is nearly equal to `z1[i+1]`. Rather than solve the equation from scratch each time for each new `E[i]`, I'd like to use the result `z1[i]` as a starting point for solving for `z1[i+1]`. Another option is to put a bound on the allowed values of `z[i+1]` based on the value of `z[i]`. Basically I'm looking to speed this section up as much as possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a bizarre use of `np.linspace`; why not `E = np.arange(Emin, Emax, Emesh)`?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your equation,

```
(d - e) / s - z - 1/z == 0
```

multiply through by `-z`.

```
z**2 + ((e - d) / 2) * z + 1 == 0
```

now it's a quadratic which we can easily solve,

```
b = (e - d) / s

z = (-b +/- (b*b - 4)**0.5) / 2
```

and the numpy code can do exactly this,

```
import numpy as np

# some made-up numbers
e_min = 1.9
e_max = 2.6
e_mesh = 0.05
d = 2.1
s = 0.45

es = np.arange(e_min, e_max, e_mesh, dtype=np.complex)

bs  = (es - d) / s
rts = np.sqrt(bs * bs - 4)
z1 = (-bs + rts) / 2
z2 = (-bs - rts) / 2
```

which, when run, produces

```
z1
Out[118]: 
array([ 0.22222222-0.97499604j,  0.16666667-0.9860133j ,
        0.11111111-0.99380799j,  0.05555556-0.9984556j ,
        0.00000000+1.j        , -0.05555556+0.9984556j ,
       -0.11111111+0.99380799j, -0.16666667+0.9860133j ,
       -0.22222222+0.97499604j, -0.27777778+0.96064536j,
       -0.33333333+0.94280904j, -0.38888889+0.92128466j,
       -0.44444444+0.89580642j, -0.50000000+0.8660254j ,
       -0.55555556+0.83147942j])

z2
Out[119]: 
array([ 0.22222222+0.97499604j,  0.16666667+0.9860133j ,
        0.11111111+0.99380799j,  0.05555556+0.9984556j ,
       -0.00000000-1.j        , -0.05555556-0.9984556j ,
       -0.11111111-0.99380799j, -0.16666667-0.9860133j ,
       -0.22222222-0.97499604j, -0.27777778-0.96064536j,
       -0.33333333-0.94280904j, -0.38888889-0.92128466j,
       -0.44444444-0.89580642j, -0.50000000-0.8660254j ,
       -0.55555556-0.83147942j])
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you might not even need to use solve!
All you want to do is solve the equation:

```
(d - E[i])/s - z - 1/z=0
```

for z. With a little help from our friend WolframAlpha, we get:

```
z=-(-d+E[i]+sqrt(d**2-2*d*E[i]+E[i]**2-4*s**2))/(2*s)
```

and

```
z=(d-E[i]+sqrt(d**2-2*d*E[i]+E[i]**2-4*s**2))/(2*s)
```

I'm not sure of your domain, so using one or both of these is your choice.

For reference, the complete function:

```
E = np.linspace(Emin,Emax,((Emax-Emin)/Emesh)+1)
z1 = np.zeros(len(E))+0j
for i in xrange(len(E)):    
    z1[i] = z #Replace z with one/both of the expressions above
```

Comment: @Trey If this answered your question, feel free to accept it as the answer!